# python pytube urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python, pytube

```
from pytube import YouTube
url = "link"

yt = YouTube(url)
stream = yt.streams.first()
stream.download()
```

This code gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "D:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    stream = yt.streams.first()
  File "D:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 324, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
  File "D:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 229, in fmt_streams
    if "adaptive_fmts" in self.player_config_args:
  File "D:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 203, in player_config_args
    self._player_config_args = self.vid_info
  File "D:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 294, in vid_info
    return dict(parse_qsl(self.vid_info_raw))
  File "D:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 124, in vid_info_raw
    self._vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)
  File "D:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 55, in get
    response = _execute_request(url, headers=extra_headers, timeout=timeout)
  File "D:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 39, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request, timeout=timeout)  # nosec
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

This code worked for me before but now it doesn't. The link i'm entering in valid and it's a youtube video link that has no copyright. Tried restarting PC or closing all browser windows but it still didn't work.

Edit: I'm using pytube version --> 10.7.0 , The link im using is 100% valid in my browser.

Comment: Can you confirm what version of pytube you are using? `import pytube; print(pytube.__version__)`

Comment: What is the link? Try pasting it in your browser. If the page is not found then your link is incorrect

Comment: This is a known issue. You need to update to `10.8.2` `python -m pip install --upgrade pytube`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: No video downloading and no error.

Comment: It would help if you provided the actual link. When not passing any argument to `download` it saves it in the current working directory. You can do `import os; print(os.getcwd()` and check if it's there

Comment: So nothing in the working directory. Strange but when i do ```YouTube(link).streams.first().download()``` outside my main code it works . I think its because of the link that i enter. So i got a pyqt5 textedit and i call .toPlainText() on it. What type of data does the link need to be? (string , char or..?). So you need an example of link here "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw" tried this one.